# JAXB add element dynamically

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is it possible to create XML Document by JAXB in such way.
As copy is between mkdir and it will be dynamic

```
<project>
    <create>
        <mkdir dest="src/java"/>
        <copy src="test/src/java" dest="src/java" />
        <mkdir dest="{projectPath}/web/META-INF"/>
    </create>
</project>
```

My java Code :-

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "project")
public class Project {    
    private Create create;
    private Tree tree;    
    public Create getCreate() {
        return create;
    }    
    public void setCreate(Create create) {
        this.create = create;
    }    
    public Tree getTree() {
        return tree;
    }    
    public void setTree(Tree tree) {
        this.tree = tree;
    }    
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Create {

    private List<Mkdir> mkdir;    
    private Buildfile buildfile;  
    private Createfile createfile; 
    private Execute execute;
    private Copy copy;

   .....
}
```

I am able to achieve same by JDOM but i want to do it by Java Object.

Or i should use any other Java Library for this.

Comment: Depends on how your `Create` class look like.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add it.

Comment: how do you get your `<copy ...>`?

Comment: Your `mkdir` consists only 2 elements? What if `copy` is missing, what if `mkdir` is empty or has more elements. You have to be more precise and maybe give some example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this annotation on class Create:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Create { ... }
```

Assuming there are no glitches in the classes you haven't shown (Tree, Buildfile, Mkdir,...) you can use the following code (where String serves as a replacement for all classes unknown to me) to marshal an XML file:

```
    void marshal() throws Exception {
        Project root = new Project();
        Create create = new Create();
        root.setCreate( create );
        create.getMkdir().add( "make dir1" );
        create.getMkdir().add( "make dir2" );
        create.setBuildfile( "buildfile1" );
        create.setCreatefile( "createfile1" );
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( Project.class );
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        m.marshal( root, System.out );
    }
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<project>
  <create>
    <mkdir>make dir1</mkdir>
    <mkdir>make dir2</mkdir>
    <buildfile>buildfile1</buildfile>
    <createfile>createfile1</createfile>
  </create>
</project>
```

I suppose the mkdirs can all be up front. If it *has* to be mixed, it's a little more complicated.

**Edit** You need a list capable of holding elements of mixed types, best subtypes of a common type.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Create {

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "mkdir", type = MkdirCommand.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "copy", type = CopyCommand.class)
    })
    private List cmds;
    public List getCmds(){
    if( cmds == null ) cmds = new ArrayList();
    return cmds;
    }
}

class Command {
}

class MkdirCommand extends Command {
    @XmlAttribute
    public String dest;
    public MkdirCommand( String d ){ dest = d; }
}

class CopyCommand extends Command {
    @XmlAttribute
    public String src;
    @XmlAttribute
    public String dest;
    public CopyCommand( String s, String d ){ src = s; dest = d; }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<project>
  <create>
    <mkdir dest="foo/dir1"/>
    <copy src="source" dest="target"/>
    <mkdir dest="bar/dir2"/>
  </create>
</project>
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem to inline the `copy` part between the `mkdir` tags.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem i were able achieve what you have done. I need it in middle

Comment: @abhishek221192 OK, see the - more complicated - variant I've added.